# Flurry events in Application onCreate() are not sent

Tags: android, flurry

I use Flurry analytics to track individual events inside my app. This works fine for all events except for those in the subclass of `Application`.

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        FlurryAgent.init(this, FLURRY_KEY);
        FlurryAgent.setCaptureUncaughtExceptions(true);

        FlurryAgent.logEvent("This event will not show up");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        FlurryAgent.logEvent("This event will not show up either");

        super.onTerminate();
    }

}
```

But all other events work fine.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FlurryAgent.logEvent("This event will show up");
    }
}
```

I would like to track an event every time the app is started, no matter which activity gets created first. Also, the fact that the Flurry initialization in `Application.onCreate()` works fine but not the logging of events seems strange to me.

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using? Have you tested this on a real device or just the emulator?

Comment: Thank you for helping me out here. I ran into the problem using SDK 6.1 but 6.2 did not solve the issue. I sent the built to a couple of testers and it seems to affect all devices and Android versions in use by them.

Comment: The session has to start before you can log events. The session doesn’t start immediately after init() on Android. Only after `Activity#onStart()` We are looking into improving the documentation around this.

Comment: Okay, I found a workaround for it.

Comment: Can you share your workaround? Thanks.

Comment: I created a wrapper class for the `FlurryAgent` that detects if an event is the first one to be sent. In that case it logs another custom event first. This way all sessions begin with the custom event.